# Connecting to mysql doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup iRedMail but during the installation process I get this error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

and by default iRedMail tries to connect to MySql with TCP and not with a system socket.

To narrow down the problem, the following works:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p
```

but this does not

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I am using mysql  Ver 14.14 on Ubuntu 14.04

Here are the relevant configuration lines of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
skip-networking=0
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Also, `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;` shows that

```
skip_networking | ON
```

Here are the relevant lines of `px aux | grep mysql`:

```
mysql    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/mnt/storage/data/mysql/ --plugin-  dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

= EDIT =

The main question here is how to turn off skip_networking

Comment: Could be a DNS issue. What does localhost resolve to?

Comment: @Donal Server:  172.31.0.2
Address: 172.31.0.2#53

Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Donal: could this be a problem? The address is not local and skip_networking is on so there is no way it will connect?

Comment: just remove the line skip-networking from my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Check your Firewall.

Or use Socket connection.

Comment: I can't use socket connection. What should I check in my firewall exactly?

Comment: for test flush your firewall. iptables -F and connect after wards

Answer (score 0):

start mysql service then try

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

for installation of mysql in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Comment: mysqld: unrecognized service

Comment: install mysql client and server

Comment: both are already installed. you are probably referring to another distribution. I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `skip-networking` and `bind-address` at the same time. You should never do this.

`skip-networking` disables TCP/IP - so just remove it.

`bind-address` means you are using TCP/IP.

Comment: I removed the line with skip-networking. but when I do `show variables;` `skip-networking` is `ON`